# GWT: How do I get a reference to a button from the RootPanel?

Tags: gwt

I'm using GWT 2.4.  In my onModuleLoad method, given a string id, how do I get a reference to an existing button on the page from the RootPanel object?  I'm trying this

```
public void onModuleLoad() {
    ...
    final Button submitButton = (Button) RootPanel.get("submit");
```

but getting the compile error, "Cannot cast from RootPanel to Button".

Edit:

I thought using an iterator would heal the pain, but no dice.  Here is the default HTML loaded (notice the button with id="submit") ...

```
<div>

    <form name="f">

        File name: <input type="text" size="25" id="filename" name="filename"

            value="" /> <input type="button" id="submit" name="submit"

            value="Submit" /> <input type="hidden" name="curId" id="curId"

            value="" />

    </form>

</div>

<div id="content"></div>
```

but this code in onModuleLoad causes a NullPointerException (because the submitButton id can't be found) ...

```
public void onModuleLoad() {

    final Button submitButton = (Button) getWidgetById("submit");
    submitButton.addStyleName("submitButton");
    ...

private Widget getWidgetById(final String id) {
    Widget eltToFind = null;
    final Iterator<Widget> iter = RootPanel.get().iterator();
    while (iter.hasNext()) {
        final Widget widget = iter.next();
        final Element elt = widget.getElement();
        if (elt.getId() != null && elt.getId().equals(id)) {
            eltToFind = widget;
            break;
        } // if
    } // while
    return eltToFind;
}
```

Thanks, - Dave

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can get your input element using `Document.get().getElementById("submit").<InputElement>cast()`, but you won't be able to get a `Button` widget out of it.

If you change your code to read `<button type="button" id="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">` instead of `<input>` (the type=button part is technically not needed, but some browsers will treat it like a type=submit if you don't), then you can use `Button.wrap()`:

```java
Button button = Button.wrap(Document.get().getElementById("submit"));
```

Answer (score 2):

Some of GWT widgets have static method wrap() which allows to convert DOM elements to widget instances.

Button submit = Button.wrap(DOM.getElementById("submit"));

Answer (score 1):

The get() method returns the RootPanel associated with the browser element, not the widget with that name.  A RootPanel is a subclass of ComplexPanel, so I think your best bet is to use the methods from ComplexPanel to iterate through the widgets and so find the one that you want that way.

Comment: Could you demonstrate how to do this?  I have tried the iterator approach (in my edit), but it is not finding an element whose id is definitely on the page.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap creates a layer and will remove all the functionalities written previously on that button.

I used the below code to resolve the same.

```
Document.get().getElementById("buttonId").getStyle().setDisplay(false)
```